# Laravel-Excel xlsx download request not working

Tags: php, http-headers, laravel-5.1, xlsx

I'm using the Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel(version 2.1) library in Laravel to download an xls file.

```
class ControllerApi extends Controller {

     private $excel;

     public function __construct(Excel $excel) {
         $this->excel = $excel;
     }

     public function getXlsFile(Request $request) {
           $this->excel->create("Report2016", function($excel) {

            // Set the title
            $excel->setTitle('My awesome report 2016');

            // Chain the setters
            $excel->setCreator('Me')->setCompany('Our Code World');

            $excel->setDescription('A demonstration to change the file properties');

            $data = [12,"Hey",123,4234,5632435,"Nope",345,345,345,345];

            $excel->sheet('Sheet 1', function ($sheet) use ($data) {
                $sheet->setOrientation('landscape');
                $sheet->fromArray($data, NULL, 'A3');
            });

        })->export("xlsx");
     }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Even though the response header seems to be okay, the browser don't download the file.

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just download something from a ajax request. Your frontend likely should be doing some extra steps like creating an  link with the content of that call.

EDIT

I can't put some code specificaly for you, as I have no idea how the frontend is made. But you could use a lib as https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/.

For example, as you are downloading some binary data for a spreadsheet:

```
http('yourBackendUrl').then(function(response) {

    var blobData = new Blob([response.data], {type: "application/xlsx"})
    saveAs(blobData, filename+'.xlsx')

}
```

Comment: Could you put some code to explain your suspicions?

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks